# Simple Copy/Paste Loop not working on each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through all the worksheets in my workbook. On each sheet, I'd like to copy a value from one cell, and paste the value on a different cell in that worksheet, and then continue on through the workbook. The code I've written loops through all the worksheets but only performs the copy paste on the sheet its on when the macro is run...

```
Sub CleanUp()

Dim ws as Worksheet

For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Range("BB2").Copy Range("A1")
Next ws

End Sub
```

In actuality, I want to run a more complicated series of alterations, but I can't even get this to work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append the worksheet to each range:

```
Sub CleanUp()

Dim ws as Worksheet

For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Range("BB2").Copy ws.Range("A1")
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfect. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution that could run faster:

```
Sub CleanUp()

Dim ws as Worksheet

For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Range("A1").Value = ws.Range("BB2").Value
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Most definitely quicker as it avoids the clipboard.  It may not be noticeable here, but is good advice and more robust.

Comment: I appreciate it. I'm fairly new to coding and didn't realize this was the difference between the .value and the copying method.

Comment: No problem, is a good practice to use the `.Value` property instead of Copy and Paste the values.