# Copy/Paste Loop through worksheets to consolidate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has approximately 300 worksheets. I'm trying to loop through each sheet, copy a specific range, and paste it on summary sheet. I need each successive paste to be put one row below the last used row. I'm newer to loops, but I think the amount of information being copied is excessive(causing an error), and I have come to understand that the .value method is much less memory intensive.

How do I incorporate the .value method to accomplish this? Here is the code I tried to write (again, I'm new to coding,sorry).

```
Sub Consolidation()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Sheets("Summary").Select

For Each ws InThisWorkbook.Sheets

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xLUp).Offset(1).Value ="ws.Range("BB1").End(xLToRight).End(xLDown).Select"

Next ws

End Sub
```

Alternatively, is there a better way to do this? Meaning, is the .value method the way to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar than:

> [Simple Copy/Paste Loop not working on each worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418078/simple-copy-paste-loop-not-working-on-each-worksheet/47418276?noredirect=1#comment81791153_47418276)

This is the way you can use the `.Value`

```
Sub WsLoop()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Summary As Worksheet

    Set Summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not ws.Name = "Summary" Then 'This will skip Summary.
            Summary.Range("A1").Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I understand this as you wrote it, but I'm not sure how to make the leap of having the values posted back on a summary sheet. I want to have one sheet where all these values (basically they're tables of the same format), but when I use copy/paste, it takes up too much memory to work.

Comment: I modified the example defining a Summary sheet (you can modify the value) and using `.Value` to copy a value from other Sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that helps a lot. In my case, I need to have a single sheet where the values are pasted one after the other, whereas here they are overwritten. How/where would I incorporate a way to find the last row on the summary sheet after each iteration of the loop?

Comment: In this example you can find the last empty cell in Column A `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub loop_through_all_worksheets_cpyPst()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = Sheets("startAtSheet")

'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate

If Not ws.Name = "SheettoPasteTo_skipCopy" Then 'This will skip Summary.
           
    Range("A2:I2").Select
'my section range had only columns till i - edit the to last column 

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("SheettoPasteTo_skipcopy").Select
'edit this sheet name to copy to 

    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   
End If
       
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = 1 'this sets cell A1 of each sheet to "1"
   
Next

starting_ws.Activate 
'activate the worksheet that was originally active

End Sub
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).